# Postfix sending mail back to itself? (Ubuntu 9.10)

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I setup Dovecot and Postfix using the "Dovecot-Postfix" package with SASL and all that.  The Dovecot part seems to be working fine but I'm having issues with Postfix.

Whenever I send a message to another address through the postfix server, two things happen.

1. the message never gets to the other address (even when I request a delivery notification, it says that it's been delivered but it's not in the spam box in the other inbox or anything)
2. The message comes back to my inbox through Dovecot as though I sent it to myself internally.

e.g. I send an email through my postfix server to my gmail account, 10 minutes later nothing shows up in my gmail account but the message comes back to me as though I was sending it to my internal address (with no errors)

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the logs show?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, most likely you wanted it to relay for a domain, but set it up to think it actually handled the mail for (was the final destination for) that domain.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up completely removing the dovecot-postfix package and reinstalling it which worked.  I believe it was an issue with relaying.